# Deploying Flask, in a flexible way to production

Tags: flask

I'm using gunicorn-flask-celery-redis-mongodb in my app.

Currently when I deploy Flask app to production, I update the code and restart the server, there is an outage of 30 seconds, but that's not really what I'm worried about.  I want to be able to switch to an old version if I find out that there is a problem with the new version, or maybe even run two parallel versions in production.

Can anyone recommend a way of deployment that wold work, and allow me to switch back and forth between versions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've put nginx in front of it, allows me to do just that.